# Row Bootstrap with image background and column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a problem. I think so simple but I don't understand the right way.

My simple code:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4">
      some text and 2 buttons
</div>

</div>
```

Well,I want a responsive backgroung image in row. Inside there's a column with some text and 2 buttons (as a figure)

[image: figure]

Important is responsive way.

Thanks for help me !

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to adapt based on the size of the browser window use this code:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

And remember don't set height and width of the image.
For more info check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?v=example#contain) article.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.row {
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
background-size: cover; /*That will make it responsive*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this way.

```
.row {
    background: url(/src/assets/images/bg_pic.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I try but  the image is not responsive!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
.row {
background: url('portfolio.jpg');
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these work for me and many others I found and tried too. I found it is not possible to make the div ( row) responsive to the same size as the image.

I also found I had to put a fixed height on the image ( or the div/row) to get the image to show at all and then become responsive... then that left an empty space between that row with the image and the next row below it.

After much searching for an answer I found other posts that clearly state that it is not possible to responsively size and resize a background image to the row it is in in height, as the image will shrink but leave the space remaining in the height of the row blank.